# Delete excel files which are older then 1 month

Tags: shell-script, files

I need to delete excel files which are older then 1 month. need to set cronjob. any suggestion for this? which script can be used to search  excel files from particular directory and delete them.

Answer (score 1):

Open up root's crontab with:

```
sudo crontab -u root -e
```

And create a new cronjob by appending this line to it:

```
60 * * * * find / -type f -iname "*.xls" -mtime +30 -exec rm -f {} \; &>/dev/null
```

With this you have created a cronjob that will be executed every hour and search your system with `find` for files with a `.xls` extension and is `+30` days old, then it'll be removed with `rm`.

If you don't want the job to be executed every hour (60 min) you have to change this `60 * * * *` to something else.

Comment: Best add `-type f` to the find before the `-name` to constrain the search to files which saves resources. Use `-iname` instead `-name` You forgot `rm -f` as for **a lot** of linux distributions `rm` is aliased to `rm -i` for root, and hence it would ask for each file.

Either use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm {}`. Or, if your find version does not support `-delete` then better use `-exec rm -f {} +` as that makes quite a difference and does not spawn a subshell for each file it deletes.

As the requester asked about Excel files in general, the pattern should be `-iname "*.xls*"`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @doktor5000. I've edited the find command so it has `-type f`, `rm -f` and `-iname "*.xls."`.

Comment: Why not use `-delete`? You still spawn a subshell for every file found that is being deleted currently.